# type of function is not recognized

Tags: typescript

The following code is using `redux` & `redux-thunk`.

```
type MyAction = Action<'action-type-1'>

export interface Action<T = any> {
  type: T
}
```

This code has no compilation errors:

```
export const f1 = function f2(action: MyAction): ThunkAction<MyAction, {}, undefined, MyAction> {
  return dispatch => {
    let advance1 = f2(action) // ts knows that advance1 is MyAction
    const result = dispatch(advance1)
    return result
  }
}
```

This code has compilation errors:

```
type F1 = (action: MyAction) => ThunkAction<MyAction, {}, undefined, MyAction>
// ts doesn't understand the type of `f2`
export const f1: F1 = function f2(action) {
  return dispatch => {
    let advance1 = f2(action)
    const result = dispatch(advance1)
    return result
  }
}
```

Errors:

```
155:10 Function implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.
    153 | type F1 = (action: MyAction) => ThunkAction<MyAction, {}, undefined, MyAction>
    154 | export const f1: F1 = function f2(action) {
  > 155 |   return dispatch => {
        |          ^
    156 |     let advance1 = f2(action)
    157 |     const result = dispatch(advance1)
    158 |     return result


157:11 'result' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
    155 |   return dispatch => {
    156 |     let advance1 = f2(action)
  > 157 |     const result = dispatch(advance1)
        |           ^
    158 |     return result
    159 |   }
    160 | }
```

---

Both of the examples has the same code. the difference is that in the second example, I extract the type to a variable.

What is the problem?

---

[redux-thunk.d.ts](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/index.d.ts)

```
/**
 * A "thunk" action (a callback function that can be dispatched to the Redux
 * store.)
 *
 * Also known as the "thunk inner function", when used with the typical pattern
 * of an action creator function that returns a thunk action.
 *
 * @template TReturnType The return type of the thunk's inner function
 * @template TState The redux state
 * @template TExtraThunkARg Optional extra argument passed to the inner function
 * (if specified when setting up the Thunk middleware)
 * @template TBasicAction The (non-thunk) actions that can be dispatched.
 */
export type ThunkAction<
  TReturnType,
  TState,
  TExtraThunkArg,
  TBasicAction extends Action
> = (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<TState, TExtraThunkArg, TBasicAction>,
  getState: () => TState,
  extraArgument: TExtraThunkArg
) => TReturnType;

/**
 * The dispatch method as modified by React-Thunk; overloaded so that you can
 * dispatch:
 *   - standard (object) actions: `dispatch()` returns the action itself
 *   - thunk actions: `dispatch()` returns the thunk's return value
 *
 * @template TState The redux state
 * @template TExtraThunkArg The extra argument passed to the inner function of
 * thunks (if specified when setting up the Thunk middleware)
 * @template TBasicAction The (non-thunk) actions that can be dispatched.
 */
export interface ThunkDispatch<
  TState,
  TExtraThunkArg,
  TBasicAction extends Action
> {
  <TReturnType>(
    thunkAction: ThunkAction<TReturnType, TState, TExtraThunkArg, TBasicAction>
  ): TReturnType;
  <A extends TBasicAction>(action: A): A;
}
```

Comment: This works for me. I get no errors: `interface ThunkAction<A, B, C, D>{ }
interface MyAction { }`

Comment: well, thats not what i'm doing here at all. please use reudx-thunk's ThunkAction, and use my MyAction.

Comment: You do have "redux" and "redux-thunk" tags here, so you might want to wait for someone with expertise in those to answer.  However if you'd like to increase your chances of getting an answer you might want to remove those dependencies from your question (e.g., introduce the relevant declarations in your example code or replace them with toy examples that still show the issue) or, barring that, provide a link to the code in a web IDE that has the dependencies already configured.  This is all part of making a [mcve] to lower the barrier to entry for answering.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem here seems to be in the circularity of types inside the return value of `f2()`. The TypeScript compiler performs both type inference (determining types of expressions based on what you do with them) and type checking (determine what you can do with expressions based on what type they are) in different "passes" or "stages".  The details of which happens when are beyond me, but a rule of thumb to follow could be: start off relying on type inference, and if the compiler infers an unexpected/undesirable type (or cannot infer a type) then use type annotations or type assertions to fix it and get type checking instead of type inference.

In your first example,

```
export const f1good = function f2(
  action: MyAction
): ThunkAction<MyAction, {}, undefined, MyAction> {
  return dispatch => {
    let advance1 = f2(action); 
    const result = dispatch(advance1);
    return result;
  };
};
```

the compiler has no problem because the function `f2()` is a fully annotated function.  Its return type, `ThunkAction<MyAction, {}, undefined, MyAction>` is given by you.  And the compiler is happy to check against that type.

In your second example,

```
type F1 = (action: MyAction) => ThunkAction<MyAction, {}, undefined, MyAction>;

export const f1bad: F1 = function f2(action) {
  return dispatch => {  // error!
    let advance1 = f2(action);
    const result = dispatch(advance1);  // error!
    return result;
  };
};
```

what happens is different.  You have typed the `f1bad` variable, but have not typed the `f2` function assigned to it.  You are relying on type inference to give `f2` its proper type from the type you gave `f1bad`.  That kind of type inference is called "[contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing)" because it operates "backwards in time" from a control-flow persective.  I mean, when running the code, *first* `f2` is defined, and *then* it is assigned to `f1bad`.  But you have defined the type of `f1bad` *first*, and want that to determine the type of `f2`.  This is actually fine and the compiler will often do just such contextual typing.  Unfortunately for you, a key piece of this contextual typing seems to happen at a later stage than some of the "forward in time" type inference for `f2` itself:

Inside the normal type inference for `f2`, its parameters and return type are inferred from how the function is implemented.  And here's where the compiler gets confused.  The return type of `f2` is itself a function which returns something of whatever type `result` is.  And the type of `result` is inferred to be the return type of `dispatch` when called with the `advance1` parameter.  And the type of the `advance1` parameter is inferred to be the return type of `f2` when called with the `action` parameter.  Uh oh, the return type of `f2` depends on the return type of `f2`.  At that point the compiler gives up, starts assigning `any` to things, and warns you about it if you have `--noImplicitAny` turned on (which you should).

It's possible that this could be considered a bug or a design limitation... I [searched](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/search?q=%22directly+or+indirectly%22+function&type=Issues) for related issues.  Sometimes issues like this were considered a [fixable bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26655), and other times they were considered an [unfixable or unlikely-to-be-fixed design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8864).  Not sure if there's an exactly matching issue.

Anyway, the way to get rid of this error is to break the circularity of the type inference by annotating or asserting something along the way.  Obviously your first example does this by explicit annotation of the whole function.  The following is the least verbose way I've found to do this for your example:

```
export const f1fixed: F1 = function f2(action) {
  return dispatch => {
    let advance1 = f2(action);
    const result: MyAction = dispatch(advance1); // annotate here
    return result;
  };
};
```

Here we've explicitly annotated that `result` is of type `MyAction`.  Now the compiler expects `f2` to return a function returning a `MyAction`, and that along with whatever contextual inference from `F1` gets done is enough for everything to succeed.

I hope that helps in some way.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCBjYBLA9gOygXik1mAPAEQCGy6GAtKJFQIzEB8A3AFBsQAeYaATsCgoMwCHwBm5aPkqEAKjiikMIJlADebKFFoQAXFDnsAvh268BURJgDOg8fQDmaNABNF4gK4YKmKOIAmAAotJV8MAzgZTDYASgM5AAtvAGtojEIo8IAaDWNc71cIcWEIV1ysggw1TW0+CGBPPixXFBswUmBERJwa0O0AGwalVwA3ZUQIeg9g8irYlih+q1tBeptPAcFcVvbO7qDSMYmpheX6xuaodc3gdm1jE3Y2XSgAMWncQ-DIhHDY3qGZIYNLhTJ-Kq5dT5KCFYqlcqwCGUVhmHj8QTWDB2fz0ABGRwMHw83nC-lm-w0oQuTRabQ6XR62Bq2gA9KyoGI+PwAITLIaCI7jHxTGbfeb3bQrbFrCAbLaKXYMg5Ck70BZsjlc3nnBq065y26Sx5sE2cdGWLE4hwlLhlImffykqrk8WUAG1A2XOl7RmAz2DYaqkWOwJuzBnKXSnE3La-dKK+n7RKHY4hyNSmlXWN3UIms1sdlQAAyAEkAEIAJXgldLAFEAMpQct14sAeQA6miLIJXklUulCKE5JW9c05OAINlhw3gJ0p8O61xgHxSP2QfA+I5p9o5OXSDYUIgE9xRBhXDY8OE2GovqElcmEsCUgARJOM+Sz+e5ORLldr59N23Qx90PY9wiYHcoEcBov1EAwggBZlDDghdtFPVcgM8ABbCARASP9V3XNItziQERzHDAJ0gZ5zAxIQRDESRJiBVI319boh13VCoN-ZciMArdeNAo8T2XPCLyvKobypbR5FHb1qIgJgQijYBAJ+ViNzBCjFMnH8eMMQiAIHISQIPUSINCeJDAU2klMlQh4E5cTz0vPcLPAqoVLmSgDHgGz4BMNggA)

Comment: Thats such a great answer. Thanks for the detailed explenation of the circular problem and the links to those issues. I learned alot. Also, I failed to find those issues by my self. can you respond on how you found those issues?